# Update ListBox in WPF with ObservableCollection containing INotifyPropertyChanged objects

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox

I'm very new to WPF, and am trying to make a `ListBox` that shows the current status of a number of tasks. More tasks can be added over time, and will be removed as they complete. The tasks are represented by an `ObservableCollection` of objects that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

When I add new items, the `ListBox` updates to show the new item, but as the task progresses, it's not showing an updated status, just the status at the start.

To set the binding at the moment, I'm just setting the `ItemSource` of the item in code. I really have *no* knowledge of how databindings work, so when terms such as Binding Path and Data Context are thrown up without explaination, I'm getting a bit lost.

Edit:
Relevant code:

In my window class I have

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DeviceWrapper> m_Devices = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DeviceWrapper>();
```

In the constructor I do:

```
DownloadJobsListBox.ItemsSource = m_DeviceConnections;
```

The XAML doesn't have any reference to the data.

In the class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged I have:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public int DownloadPercentDone
{
    get { return m_DownloadPercentDone; }
    private set 
    {
        m_DownloadPercentDone = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{   
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if(handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I have a method called from the main window in the device object, which starts a backgroundworker. I use the ProgressChanged event handlers to update the DownloadPercentDone property.

Comment: *"I really have no knowledge of how databindings work"*. Then why not first read about these things in a book before writing WPF programs? Read **at least** the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN, and make yourself familiar with the basic concepts explained there.

Comment: Because my boss isn't a software engineer, and isn't going to let me spend a week reading a book about WPF. I want to try to move us away from winforms, because it's caused us no end of problems in the past, but the only way I'm going to able to do this is a "learn by doing" approach, relying on MSDN, stack overflow, and other online resources. That's fine for most problems I've encountered, but not this one, which is why I came here.
Edit: Your original comment didn't have the link. I'll look at that.

Comment: Read a WPF book at home, after work. You're lost without understanding the basic concepts, and will end up with the same problems you had before with WinForms.

Comment: At least post the relevant parts of your code. Otherwise it is impossible to tell where your problem is.

Comment: You should read the [Data Binding Overview‎](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: You have to learn databinding some time.  Why not just learn it now?  You don't save time trying to bind trial and error.

Comment: I've added some source code and am reading the overview page linked. I had been reading about databindings anyway, but wanted to be clear I didn't yet fully understand all the terminology around them, which is why I mentioned it.